# Why date child automatically creating sub children in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app user can select a date and time when he required a particular service.
For stopping the user from selecting the time which is already selected by someone else I'm making `alreadyBooked`DB in firebase, [image: Here is my DB].

I put the value of `date` child from `bookingTime` DB as a child in `alreadyBooked` DB but as you can see it creates sub-child by breaking the date,months and year. Format of my date is dd/MM/yyyy.

**Code for updating the value**

```
String date = bDate.getText().toString();
        bookingDetails.put("date", date);
 bookingTimeDB.child(pushKey).updateChildren(bookingDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this, "Booking Confirmed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alreadyBookedTimeDB.child(date).updateChildren(bookedDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this, "booked time put", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

How can I put the whole date as one child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating a node in a Firebase database that looks like this one `dd/MM/yyyy`, Firebase sees each vales as a new node. This is happening because Firebase creates a link for each particular location. Each node has his own particular reference (url). Because the `backslash` is used as a separator in your url, Firebase creates those 3 nodes. To solve this, just change the format of your date. One possible way would be:

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out just after posting the question but **Thanks Alex** it is the second time you came to my rescue. :)